# Adding layout to static files in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I am using GitHub pages to publish files from a project. These files are Java source code files, which I have been able to add as static files into Jekyll as a collection. I would need to apply a layout to these files for, e.g., code formatting. I am unable to do this.

My static source code files are in a collection defined in `_config.yml`:

```
collections_dir: material
collections:
  cse-solutions:
    output: true
```

This part of my site works fine: `.java`-files under `material/_cse-solutions` appear on the static site into `/cse-solutions`.

However, I would need to include a title and code formatting. For this I am trying to apply a layout to these static files. My current effort is the following. First, in `_config.yml` I set

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "cse-solutions"
    values:
      layout: java-code
```

Then I have a file `_layouts/java-code.html` with contents, for simplicity at this point

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test title </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Test code page heading </h1>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this layout has no effect on the `.java` files on the site. To be honest, if the layout were effective, I do not know whether the output would even have `.java`-suffix. Still, I can not find any corresponding `.html`-pages on the site either.

Can this be done? If it can, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I suspect Jekyll just ignores layout for static files. Using `jsonify` from Liquid I can actually print the value of this collection, and there I can see that the system has correctly set, for these static files:

```
”layout”:”java_code”
```

But there is absolutely no effect in the formatting of these files.

(The underscore, that is, `java_code` instead of `java-code` is not an error here, because I noticed that some parts of Jekyll do not like dashes in identifiers, so I changed dashes to underscores everywhere. I think Ruby does not allow dashes in identifiers.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over complicating things a bit. If I understand correctly, you are trying to simply display the actual source code on your page correct? For example you would like your code to look like:

```java
class HelloWorld 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
    } 
}
```

If this is the case, you can simply save the written source code as a [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) file (.md) and let the [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/) mardkown converter handle displaying it correctly. To do this you need to make sure that you have the following in your `_config.yml` file:

```
kramdown:
  # Use GitHub flavored markdown, including triple backtick fenced code blocks
  input: GFM
  # Jekyll 3 and GitHub Pages now only support rouge for syntax highlighting
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

This will make sure kramdown is enabled and will use [rouge](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge) for syntax highlighting if you would like.

Then for each page you want, simply create a `pagename.md` file and add at least the following [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) at the very top of the page:

```
---
layout: java-code
title:  "Here is my source code page"
---
```

This tells jekyll to use the "java-code" layout you already made and to define the title for the page as whatever you put in the quotes. After the front matter, simply copy your source code into a code block for markdown. It is very simple, all you need to do is have a line with ```` ``` ```` before and after you code. You can optionally have the first line be ```` ```java ```` to tell rouge to highlight for java syntax to make it easier to read.

You can put any markdown text outside of the code block that you would like as well. That means you can have a description of the code, or even break the code into segments with text descriptions before each part.

To put it all together you file should look something like:

````
---
layout: java-code
title:  "Here is my source code page"
---

Here is my simple "Hello, world" program:

```java
class HelloWorld 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
    } 
} 
```
````

Check out the [docs page for posts](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/) on jekyll's website for more info, and if you are unfamiliar with markdown there are tons of guides on writing with it if you do a quick google search (its how stackoverflow answers are formatted!).

Comment: The reason for such a complicated approach (via collections) is that I have *a lot* of of these `.java`-files, and they are generated automatically ("tangled" from `.org`-files). They will also change with time. So converting them to pages has to be automatic. But if it turns out that Jekyll can not do it, I can do the conversion to Markdown before handing them over to Jekyll. But that would require another component and a step to a process that would otherwise be ready and automatic.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out a different approach, but in my experience I believe you will need at least some front matter for Jekyll to render the page. The defaults set in _config.yml will be added then I believe. My best guess for making a solution would be to use javascript on a page you create to loop through the files in your solutions directory and output them into a markdown block. I'm on mobile now, but I'll try and take a look into it tonight